# Serial port communication issue (Avery weight) C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, communication

Hello dear programers I am trying to connect Avery weight G236 with PC over RS232.
But every time the weight retuns "insane".

```
">>6>>>\u0016\u0016\u0016>>6\u0016\u0016\u0016\u0016\u0016\u0016\u0016>\u0016\u0016\u0016>>"
```

My serial port configuration is (Baund rate 2400, Data bits 6, Stop bit two.). I tried to change these parameters but return was only "?" questioner or nothing.

Have someone any idea to solve this issue ?

Comment: You are getting normal response since it is repetitive.  The normal default Baud Rate for a device is 9600, 8 bits, one stop bit.  Your Baud Rate is probably wrong.  Nobody every use 2 stop bits these days.  Again 6 data bits are insane.

Comment: I reconfigure my program to parameters above (9600,8,one stop bit)... But every time returns me this : "\n?\r" . This weight is probably 10 years old.

Comment: The communication string should looks like this "<STX>GW<ETX><CR>", but I couldn't find any datasheet for serial-port communication for this weight. I'am trying to contact producer and aslo seller but noone response me.

Comment: You are getting 0x0A,0x3F, 0x0D which is very good.  Try putting some weight on the scale and see if you get different results.  The actual order is "?\r\n".

Comment: I put the weight on the scale but nothing change resulti si the same... ?\r\n ....Have you any idea what should be wrong ?

Comment: Read the Manual.  Some scales require a command to get wight.  Others send automatically.  Then some have option to do both.  I suspect the question mark indicates the scale is ready.

Comment: This is what I found about communication
https://imgur.com/a/rKSGStG
Can you look at this please...

Comment: The image is blank.

Comment: Sorry my mystake
https://ibb.co/DKLSsgM
https://ibb.co/hR4105L

This links should be right.

Comment: You have absolute right, it was only wrong setting in scale... it sends data continously... Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve issue related to scale serial-port comunication without any datasheet. It was random trying and configuring serial port in scale. Finally  jdweng help my out. In coment wrote the most common settings for scales (my scale is Avery Weight-Tronix G236).

> The normal default Baud Rate for a device is 9600, 8 bits, one stop bit.

On the end few informations about Avery Weight-Tronix scale settings:

How to show up menu ?

> Hold PRINT button on the scale for few seconds

How to set serial-port comunication ?

> Buttons SAMPLE = forward in menu, TARE - backward in menu, ZERO - confirm.

Try to find in settings menu mark `SERIAL` confirm with `ZERO`. In this submenu you can choose everithing related with serial-port comunication.

In my case (I couldn't find any manual from scale). I must choose `broad` which meanse the scale continuously sending weight to PC. It's not the best solution, but for my purpose it is enough.